# Что можно получить c <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>?

Tags: android, sdk, android-broadcastreceiver, contentprovider, intent-filter

Что можно получить с помощью BroadcastReceiver и ContentProvider, кроме события включения, выключения приложения? Безопасен ли этот чужой код?

```
       <provider
                    android:authorities="${applicationId}.elephantprovider"
                    android:name="com.elephant.data.ElephantDataProvider"
                    android:exported="true"
                    android:multiprocess="false"/>
                <receiver android:name="com.elephant.data.ElephantBroadcastReceiver">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
                        <data android:scheme="package"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

Декомпилированый jar:
package com.elephant.data;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import com.elephant.data.p000a.C0016g;
    import com.elephant.data.p012g.C0082a;

    public class ElephantBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static {
            String str = C0082a.af;
        }

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
                ((BroadcastReceiver) Class.forName(C0016g.class.getName()).newInstance()).onReceive(context, intent);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
            }
        }
    }

package com.elephant.data;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.elephant.data.p000a.C0018i;

public class ElephantDataProvider extends ContentProvider {
    public int delete(Uri uri, String str, String[] strArr) {
        return C0018i.m37a().m40a(uri, str, strArr);
    }

    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        C0018i.m37a();
        return C0018i.m38b();
    }

    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues) {
        return C0018i.m37a().m42a(uri, contentValues);
    }

    public boolean onCreate() {
        C0018i.m37a().m43a(getContext());
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] strArr, String str, String[] strArr2, String str2) {
        return C0018i.m37a().m41a(uri, strArr, str, strArr2, str2);
    }

    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues contentValues, String str, String[] strArr) {
        return C0018i.m37a().m39a(uri, contentValues, str, strArr);
    }
}
```

Остальные классы белиберда.

Comment: что в вашем понимании безопасный?

Comment: Это SDK  ELEPHANTDATA(www.elephantdata.net), который собирает статистику(Была добавлена jar-библиотека). Возможен ли сбор другой информации? И не будет ли приложение забанено Google?

Comment: конкретно этот код может собирать данные об установке и удалении приложений. Что делает остальная часть кода, не узнаешь, пока не посмотришь.

Comment: Я декомпилировал jar. Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Меня интересует один вопрос: безопасность.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безопасность в отрыве от требований к ней - не существует. К примеру, добавление в приложение троянов от AirPush, до определенного момента, было не только неплохо, но отличной практикой. Те, кто так делал - это не вирусописатели, а партнеры. Но в какой-то момент видимо поток жалоб переполнил все мыслимые пределы и приложения, которые использовали эту гадость, внезапно стали очень плохими. А пока правила рожали, Гуглоплей пополнялся приложениями вида "эйрпуш-детектор".

Данный метод позволяет узнавать о том, какие приложения были установлены. К примеру, так компания снимает статистику о том, чем пользователи пользуются, какой софт ставят и тому подобное. В принципе, ничего криминального... Но есть нюанс. К примеру, таким образом авторы сети смогут контролировать "проданные инсталлы", т.е. узнать, поставил ли пользователь рекламируемое приложений. Вы ведь добровольно становитесь членом ботнета, правда? Вторая проблема - это вторжение в частную жизнь, таким образом компания может узнать о приватных, нигде не опубликованных приложениях, чему пользователи явно не обрадуются.

А можно ли это постить в Гуглоплей, зависит от правил самого Гуглоплея. Вполне возможно, что сегодня это хорошая партнерская программа с крутыми бенефитами (или хотя бы статистикой, иногда и за 30 серебренников продаются). А завтра за эту гадость последует бан.

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже склоняюсь к решению - не рисковать, да и ботнет не привлекает.

Comment: @RuslanChepizhko, бан в  Гуглоплейе ещё не самое страшное. Сбор статистики, юридически, - это обработка персональных данных и регулируется соответствующим законом, предусматривающим административную и даже уголовную ответственность. А тут Вы понятия не имеете какие именно данные собирает библиотека, но априори знаете, что будете продавать их третим лицам.

Comment: Хорошо если продавать. Некоторые это делают ради красивых картинок.